# Why is is the compiler telling me "Type misMatch for App message" when they are the same type

Tags: xamarin.forms, f#, elm-architecture

So, I've been fighting with the compiler on a type error.

This code was working as of a couple days ago.

Type misMatch for App level message

App.fs snippets

```ml
module App =
    type Msg =
        | ConnectionPageMsg of ConnectionPage.Msg
        | CodeGenPageMsg of CodeGenPage.Msg
//...
    let update (msg : Msg) (model : Model) =
        match msg with
        | ConnectionPageMsg msg ->
            let m, cmd = ConnectionPage.update msg model.ConnectionPageModel
            { model with ConnectionPageModel = m }, cmd
        | CodeGenPageMsg msg ->
            let m, cmd = CodeGenPage.update msg model.CodeGenPageModel
            { model with CodeGenPageModel = m }, cmd
//...
    let runner =
        Program.mkProgram init update view
        |> Program.withConsoleTrace
        |> XamarinFormsProgram.run app
```

I've added explicit aliases and the original error :

```
Type mismatch. Expecting a
    'App.Msg -> App.Model -> App.Model * Cmd<App.Msg>'    
but given a
    'App.Msg -> App.Model -> App.Model * Cmd<Msg>'    
The type 'App.Msg' does not match the type 'Msg'
```

Became these:

```
App.fs(50,50): Error FS0001: The type 'PocoGen.Page.ConnectionPage.Msg' does not match the type 'PocoGen.Page.CodeGenPage.Msg' (FS0001) (PocoGen)
```

```
App.fs(32,32): Error FS0001: Type mismatch. 
Expecting a 'App.Msg -> App.Model -> App.Model * Cmd<App.Msg>'    
but given a 'App.Msg -> App.Model -> App.Model * Cmd<Msg>'    
The type 'App.Msg' does not match the type 'Msg' (FS0001) (PocoGen)
```

### Other remarks

Right before these errors started appearing I was working on converting a blocking syncronous call to a async command in the ConnectionTestPage and removed the calling code for the cmd hoping that would fix it. (It did not)

ConnectionPage.fs Messages

```ml
type Msg =
    | UpdateConnectionStringValue of string
    | UpdateConnectionStringName of string
    | TestConnection
    | TestConnectionComplete of Model
    | SaveConnectionString of ConnectionStringItem
    | UpdateOutput of string
```

ConnectionPage.fs update

```ml
let update (msg : Msg) (m : Model) : Model * Cmd<Msg> =
    match msg with
    | UpdateConnectionStringValue conStringVal ->
        { m with
              ConnectionString =
                  { Id = m.ConnectionString.Id
                    Name = m.ConnectionString.Name
                    Value = conStringVal }
              CurrentFormState =
                  match hasRequredSaveFields m.ConnectionString with
                  | false -> MissingConnStrValue
                  | _ -> Valid }, Cmd.none

    | UpdateConnectionStringName conStringName ->
        { m with
              ConnectionString =
                  { Id = m.ConnectionString.Id
                    Name = conStringName
                    Value = m.ConnectionString.Value }
              CurrentFormState =
                  match hasRequredSaveFields m.ConnectionString with
                  | false -> MissingConnStrValue
                  | _ -> Valid }, Cmd.none

    | UpdateOutput output -> { m with Output = output }, Cmd.none
    | TestConnection -> m, Cmd.none
    | TestConnectionComplete testResult -> { m with Output = testResult.Output + "\r\n" }, Cmd.none
    | SaveConnectionString(_) -> saveConnection m, Cmd.none
```

I've played with the Fsharp Version (because incidentally I did update to `4.7.2` a bit before getting this error)

### The Full Repo:

https://github.com/musicm122/PocoGen_Fsharp/tree/master/PocoGen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two branches of the `match` inside `App.update` have different types. The first branch has type `App.Model * Cmd<ConnectionPage.Msg>` and the second page has type `App.Model * Cmd<CodeGenPage.Msg>`.

You can't generally do that. This, for example, wouldn't compile:

```
let x = 
    match y with
    | true -> 42
    | false -> "foo"
```

What type is `x` here? Is it `int` or is it `string`? Doesn't compute. A `match` expression has to have all branches of the same type.

---

To convert `Cmd<ConnectionPage.Msg>` into a `Cmd<App.Msg>` (by wrapping the message in `ConnectionPageMsg`) you can use `Cmd.map`:

```
let update (msg : Msg) (model : Model) =
    match msg with
    | ConnectionPageMsg msg ->
        let m, cmd = ConnectionPage.update msg model.ConnectionPageModel
        { model with ConnectionPageModel = m }, Cmd.map ConnectionPageMsg cmd
    | CodeGenPageMsg msg ->
        let m, cmd = CodeGenPage.update msg model.CodeGenPageModel
        { model with CodeGenPageModel = m }, Cmd.map CodeGenPageMsg cmd
```

Comment: Thanks @fyodor-soikin you are awesome. I thought the app message discriminated union would have done it for me. I'm still trying to grok Cmds and Cmd Messages.